# C# Linux Framebuffer Unsafe byte[] to CairoSharp ImageSurface

Tags: c#, cairo, framebuffer, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to create an image surface in c# CairoSharp using these two constructors:

`public ImageSurface(byte[] data, Format format, int width, int height, int stride); public ImageSurface(IntPtr data, Format format, int width, int height, int stride);`

I am trying to get the array of the linux framebuffer from a memorymappedfile:

`var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("/dev/fb0", FileMode.Open, null, (3840 * 2160 * (32 / 8)));`

I know I have to use an unsafe context to get it but am unsure the proper syntax to get the sequential pointer from the memeoryMapped object.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors for the ImageSurface will not work with the MemoryMappedFile directly. You will have to Read bytes from the MemoryMappedFile and use those bytes to create the ImageSurface.

Comment: I'm ok if i dont use MemoryMappedFile, I would prefer to use cairo ImageSurface but cannot get the syntax right to give it a pointer to the framebuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I never used C# on Linux before so I don't really know if all those objects are available but maybe like this?

```
private static void test()
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("some image");
    BitmapData imgData = null;
    try
    {
        imgData = bmp.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
            bmp.PixelFormat
        );

        int finalLength = imgData.Stride * imgData.Height;
        byte[] buf = new byte[finalLength];
        IntPtr ptr = imgData.Scan0;
        
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, buf, 0, finalLength);
        bmp.UnlockBits(imgData);
        
        // Pointer to first byte lives inside of fixed context.
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* p = buf)
            {
                // your cairo code...
            }
        }

        // Alternative...
        var ptPinned = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(
            buf, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr ptCairo = ptPinned.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        ptPinned.Free();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (imgData != null) {
            bmp.UnlockBits(imgData);
        }
    }
}
```

In any case I am certain that you have to pass the pointer of an already allocated buffer. In the test above I just loaded the image pixels of a bitmap into a byte array. In order to get the pointer you Marshal it or use fixed. That is all on Windows though.